# Can I connect a remote control relay to a arduino uno board by disabling the remote control in the relay?

Tags: arduino-uno

I was making a home automation system by making some of the appliances in the home like fans and lights voice activated. But by mistake I bought a remote controlled relay in place of a normal relay from a shop and return does not seems possible. So I want to know if I will be able to use that remote controlled relay in this project?

Comment: You could, let the Arduino control the remote, which activates the relays.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like to work with mains, so I use those outlets and connect a [433MHz transmitter](http://www.ebay.com/itm/NEW-433Mhz-RF-transmitter-link-kit-for-Arduino-ARM-MC-U-Remote-control-Sale-/321975775117?hash=item4af7406f8d:g:ed8AAOSwFqJWlzgA) to the arduino to activate the outlets.

You'd have to check the frequency of the unit, and see if anyone have decoded the transmitted data package.

If that doesn't float you're boat, you could open up the unit, and remove/desolder the relay. Add a transistor, and flyback diode and you're done. Just be careful with mains power.

Comment: Why use a flyback diode? I assume because it's a mech. relay - I've used these, and had problems one wouldn't expect when switching at ~1 sec intervals for tests. Do you place it between VCC and GND on the relay? (mine were 5V relays which were supposedly isolated from higher currents, but not from the relay 'motor' itself) Did I just answer my own question? Edit: more precisely, the arduino would be reset after the relay went a bit haywire; failing to switch, seitching several other channels.

Comment: @user400344 please create a new question instead of hijacking someone else's question.

Comment: I would if I could, but it appears I am prevented from posting new questions. I'll just try using a diode from GND to VCC, thanks anyway.